# Replace only if at the beginning of the string

Tags: vbscript

I am creating a script that opens specify a key in regedit, the problem is I need remoear abbreviations (since not that LastKey key does not support) and it can happen to interfere with the key in the correct location.

**Example:**

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\HKLM\SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\Global\OEM\WhiteList
```

**As it should be:**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\HKLM\SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\Global\OEM\WhiteList
```

**As it is currently:**

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\Global\OEM\WhiteList
```

**Note:** There is a key that has least one letter, so should work with it as well "HKU\" (HKEY_USERS)

**My code:**

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim sKey, bFound
'-----------------------------------------------
Sub Main()
NameScript = "Jump to Key"
MsgScript1 = "Type the Registry path."
MsgScript2 = "Not found."
'-----------------------------------------------
sKey = Inputbox(MsgScript1,NameScript,sKey)
If sKey = "" Then WScript.quit()
'-----------------------------------------------
sKey = sKey & "\"
sKey = Replace(sKey, "\\", "\", 1, -1, 1)
sKey = Replace(sKey, "HKCR\", "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\", 1, -1, 1)
sKey = Replace(sKey, "HKCU\", "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\", 1, -1, 1)
sKey = Replace(sKey, "HKLM\", "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\", 1, -1, 1)
sKey = Replace(sKey, "HKU\", "HKEY_USERS\", 1, -1, 1)
sKey = Replace(sKey, "HKCC\", "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\", 1, -1, 1)
'-----------------------------------------------
with CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  on error resume next            ' turn off error trapping
    sValue = .regread(sKey)       ' read attempt
    bFound = (err.number = 0)     ' test for success
  on error goto 0                 ' restore error trapping
end with
'
if not bFound then
'-----------------------------------------------
  Msgbox MsgScript2,vbInformation,NameScript
  Call Main
'-----------------------------------------------
  Else
'-----------------------------------------------
KillProc "Regedit.exe"
WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit\Lastkey",sKey,"REG_SZ"
WshShell.Run "Regedit.exe", 1,True
Call Main
End if
Set WshShell = Nothing
End Sub
On Error Resume Next
Main
IF Err.Number Then
WScript.Quit 4711
End if
'-----------------------------------------------
Sub KillProc( myProcess )
'Purpose: Kills a process and waits until it is truly dead

    Dim blnRunning, colProcesses, objProcess
    blnRunning = False

    Set colProcesses = GetObject( _
                       "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}" _
                       ).ExecQuery( "Select * From Win32_Process", , 48 )
    For Each objProcess in colProcesses
        If LCase( myProcess ) = LCase( objProcess.Name ) Then
            ' Confirm that the process was actually running
            blnRunning = True
            ' Get exact case for the actual process name
            myProcess  = objProcess.Name
            ' Kill all instances of the process
            objProcess.Terminate()
        End If
    Next

    If blnRunning Then
        ' Wait and make sure the process is terminated.
        ' Routine written by Denis St-Pierre.
        Do Until Not blnRunning
            Set colProcesses = GetObject( _
                               "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}" _
                               ).ExecQuery( "Select * From Win32_Process Where Name = '" _
                             & myProcess & "'" )
            WScript.Sleep 100 'Wait for 100 MilliSeconds
            If colProcesses.Count = 0 Then 'If no more processes are running, exit loop
                blnRunning = False
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly the issue you're having is. You are replacing the short version e.g. "HKLM" with the full name. Is that what you mean to do? Is it not working? What problem are you having?

Comment: I redid the question, with examples of the problem.

Comment: So "Example" is what the user types in to your InputBox. You then posted two more things, but I don't understand which you want it to be - the one you titled "Instead of being:" or the one titled "Stay:"?

Comment: The following occurs when the User enters an abbreviated key the script renames the same, the problem is that if you have other correspondence in the key it will also rename, what need is the script just rename the first correspondence that the case would be the beginning key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the fifth parameter of `Replace`. That tells the function how many instances of the text you're searching for should be replaced. `-1` means ALL. So if the registry path contains "HKLM\" 5 times and you say `Replace(path,"HKLM\", "blah", 1, -1, 1)`, that will replace ALL five instances of "HKLM\" in `path` with "blah".

So your fifth parameter should be the number of occurrences found that you want replaced. If you only want to replace the first one, it should be `1` - e.g. `Replace(path, "HKLM\", "blah", 1, 1, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the final result of my script:

```
If WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevated") = False Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ /elevated", "", "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
End If

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim BoxKey, sKey, bFound
'-----------------------------------------------
Sub Main()
NameScript = "Jump to Key"
MsgScript1 = "Type the Registry path."
MsgScript2 = "Not found."
'-----------------------------------------------
BoxKey = Inputbox(MsgScript1,NameScript,BoxKey)
If BoxKey = "" Then WScript.quit()
'-----------------------------------------------
sKey = BoxKey & "\"
sKey = Replace(sKey, "\\", "\", 1, -1, 1)
sKey = Replace(sKey, "HKCR\", "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\", 1, 1, 1)
sKey = Replace(sKey, "HKCU\", "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\", 1, 1, 1)
sKey = Replace(sKey, "HKLM\", "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\", 1, 1, 1)
sKey = Replace(sKey, "HKU\", "HKEY_USERS\", 1, 1, 1)
sKey = Replace(sKey, "HKCC\", "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\", 1, 1, 1)
'-----------------------------------------------
with CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  on error resume next            ' turn off error trapping
    sValue = .regread(sKey)       ' read attempt
    bFound = (err.number = 0)     ' test for success
  on error goto 0                 ' restore error trapping
end with
'
if not bFound then
'-----------------------------------------------
  Msgbox MsgScript2,vbInformation,NameScript
  Call Main
'-----------------------------------------------
  Else
'-----------------------------------------------
KillProc "Regedit.exe"
sKey = Left(sKey, (LEN(sKey) -1))
WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit\Lastkey",sKey,"REG_SZ"
WshShell.Run "Regedit.exe", 1,True
Call Main
End if
Set WshShell = Nothing
End Sub
On Error Resume Next
Main
IF Err.Number Then
WScript.Quit 4711
End if
'-----------------------------------------------
Sub KillProc( myProcess )
'Purpose: Kills a process and waits until it is truly dead

    Dim blnRunning, colProcesses, objProcess
    blnRunning = False

    Set colProcesses = GetObject( _
                       "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}" _
                       ).ExecQuery( "Select * From Win32_Process", , 48 )
    For Each objProcess in colProcesses
        If LCase( myProcess ) = LCase( objProcess.Name ) Then
            ' Confirm that the process was actually running
            blnRunning = True
            ' Get exact case for the actual process name
            myProcess  = objProcess.Name
            ' Kill all instances of the process
            objProcess.Terminate()
        End If
    Next

    If blnRunning Then
        ' Wait and make sure the process is terminated.
        ' Routine written by Denis St-Pierre.
        Do Until Not blnRunning
            Set colProcesses = GetObject( _
                               "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}" _
                               ).ExecQuery( "Select * From Win32_Process Where Name = '" _
                             & myProcess & "'" )
            WScript.Sleep 100 'Wait for 100 MilliSeconds
            If colProcesses.Count = 0 Then 'If no more processes are running, exit loop
                blnRunning = False
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```